# How to pass array of objects type in MediatoR patterns?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, design-patterns, mediator

Hope You are doing well!

I am using MediatoR design pattern in which i want to accept array of collections as an object in my controller. Earlier i was using as a single object but now how can i allow the MediatoR to accept array as parameter.

From:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<int>>>
  AddField(**AddFieldCommand** objFieldCommand)
```

To:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<int>>> 
 AddField(**AddFieldCommand[]** objFieldCommand)
```

I tried doing this but it is giving me the below error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0311  The type 'Application.Commands.Fields.AddFieldCommand[]' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRequest' in the generic type or method 'IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Application.Commands.Fields.AddFieldCommand[]' to 'MediatR.IRequest<Application.Common.ServiceResponse<int>>'.   Application C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Projects\Source Code\Application\Commands\Fields\AddFieldCommand.cs    28  Active


   public class AddFieldCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<AddFieldCommandAggregate, ServiceResponse<int>>
{
    private readonly IFieldsService _fieldService;

    public AddFieldCommandHandler(IFieldsService fieldService)
    {
        _fieldService = fieldService;
    }

    public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Handle(AddFieldCommandAggregate request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _fieldService.AddField(request: request, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

error comes in line public class AddFieldCommandHandler which is marked as bold.
Can any one please help me?

Comment: You are not showing all the code that actually causes the problem. Also is there any specific reason you type Mediato**R**, is it a specific name?

Comment: Thank you @LukeVo for your reply. Not really any reasons for typing as MediatoR. However code point of view i have created a simple Mediator design pattern web api inside which i want to accept array of object instead of only single object/record

Comment: Please post the actual code that causes the problem. Changing the signature of the method should be fine but the calling has to be updated to match the new signature as well. That's where the error is, isn't it? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

By your setup i suspect you have some handler that accepts `AddFieldCommand` and invokes some method with it. Now you want to perform most probably a loop to handle all items.

So i suspect you roughly have code similar to this:

```
public async Task Handle(AddFieldCommand data)
{
    // here you have all the logic
    PerformAction(data);
}
```

so now this would be needed to be refactored to:

```
public async Task Handle(AddFieldCommandAggregate multiData)
{
    foreach(var data in mulitData.Data)
    {
        // here you have all the logic
        PerformAction(data);
    }
}
```

and you would need to define aggregate class:

```
public class AddFieldCommandAggregate
{
    public AddFieldCommand[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Michal for your response. I tries the above code however it did not worked. It still gives me the same error. I have added my piece of code above. Error in line

Comment: `AddFieldCommandAggregate` should implement `IRequest<ServiceResponse<int>>` and AddFieldCommand` should not implement IRequest interface.